# Split screen keyboard in Qt 4.7.4

Tags: qt, qml

Qt 4.7.4 documentation states this "Text input improvements – Support for split-screen virtual keyboard"

But, I couldn't find any information on how to use it in QML?

Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable the splitscreen keyboard with an ApplicationAttribute

Somewhere in your main.cpp you have to call

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_S60DisablePartialScreenInputMode, false)
```